GridBagLayout gridwidth=2 not working for second JButton
I'm trying to get second cell width to be 2 but some weird reason GridBagLayout is making first cell width to be 2 instead of second cell. How do I fix this?
Here's my code:
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.*;
public class LearnGridBagLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridbaglayout = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(gridbaglayout);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Hello World!");
        GridBagConstraints gridbagconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbagconstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridbagconstraints.weightx = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.weighty = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridbagconstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridbagconstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.gridheight = 1;
        panel.add(button,gridbagconstraints);
        
        JButton input = new JButton();
        GridBagConstraints gridbagconstraints2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbagconstraints2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridbagconstraints2.weightx = 1;
        gridbagconstraints2.weighty = 1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridwidth=2;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridheight=1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridx = 1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridy=0;
        panel.add(input,gridbagconstraints2);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


I'm trying to get both cells to fill whole width and second cell to be with width length 2.

can you please explain what you want to achieve by doing gridwidth=2? And what is meant by "s making first cell width to be 2 instead of second cell"? I suspect you are misinterpreting  how that Layout is intended to work (e.g. gridwidth is the NUMBER of cells/columns occupied by a component, and sine there is only one row, the number of columns doesn't matter) - maybe (re-)consulting the official tutorial can help: How to Use GridBagLayout

I want second column to be twice as large as first column. I also want second button to fill two columns. I fixed it with weightx = 0.25 for first column and weightx=0.75 for second column.

BTW there is no need to create a second GridBagConstraints, it can be re-used after it has been used in the add() call

That’s not what gridwidth does.
GridBagLayout creates rectangular cells, but those cells are not all the same size like a graph paper grid.  Each row can have a different height, and each column can have a different width.  GridBagLayout only makes sure each row is aligned and each column is aligned.
gridbagconstraints2.gridwidth=2; only tells the GridBagLayout that it should make the input button take up two columns.  It does not say anything about how wide those columns are.
Since there are no other components in that column, that button is the only child which determines the width of those two columns.  So, together those two columns will be wide enough for that button’s preferred width, and no wider.
You could, of course, force the button’s preferred size to something wider, but that is not the right way to address this.  Hard-coding pixel sizes is almost never correct, since fonts render in different ways on different systems (and buttons may have different borders and margins on different systems).
GridBagLayout is really only for alignment of components with each other.  To accomplish what you want, you’ll want to use SpringLayout.  SpringLayout is complicated and making mistakes with it is unfortunately easy, but it can enforce mathematical relationships between component sizes.
Using SpringLayout looks like this:
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Spring;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class RelativeWidthsDemo {

    private final JFrame frame;

    private final JButton button;
    private final JButton input;

    public RelativeWidthsDemo() {
        button = new JButton("Hello World!");
        input = new JButton();

        Dimension unlimited =
            new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        button.setMaximumSize(unlimited);
        input.setMaximumSize(unlimited);

        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

        SpringLayout.Constraints buttonConstraints =
            new SpringLayout.Constraints(
                Spring.constant(0),
                Spring.constant(0),
                Spring.width(button),
                Spring.height(button));

        SpringLayout.Constraints inputConstraints =
            new SpringLayout.Constraints(
                buttonConstraints.getWidth(),
                buttonConstraints.getY(),
                Spring.scale(buttonConstraints.getWidth(), 2),
                buttonConstraints.getHeight());

        panel.add(button, buttonConstraints);
        panel.add(input, inputConstraints);

        // Tell layout its right edge and bottom edge should match
        // right and bottom edges of the 'input' button.
        layout.putConstraint(
            SpringLayout.EAST, panel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, input);
        layout.putConstraint(
            SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, input);

        frame = new JFrame("Relative Widths Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new RelativeWidthsDemo().show());
    }
}


I found the solution. The weights have to be same as grid width. Here's my code:
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.*;
public class LearnGridBagLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridbaglayout = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(gridbaglayout);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Hello World!");
        GridBagConstraints gridbagconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbagconstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridbagconstraints.weightx = 0.25;
        gridbagconstraints.weighty = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridbagconstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridbagconstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.gridheight = 1;
        gridbagconstraints.anchor =GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        panel.add(button,gridbagconstraints);
        
        JButton input = new JButton();
        GridBagConstraints gridbagconstraints2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbagconstraints2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridbagconstraints2.weightx = 0.75;
        gridbagconstraints2.weighty = 1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridwidth=2;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridheight=1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridx = 1;
        gridbagconstraints2.gridy=0;
        gridbagconstraints2.anchor =GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        panel.add(input,gridbagconstraints2);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


This solution does not make the second button twice the size. First the preferred size of each button is calculated. Then if there is "extra" space in the frame the extra space is allocated at 25% to the first button and 75% to the second button. So in your simple example the second button may look to be approximately twice the size. In order you truly have the second button twice the size then you need: 1) the preferred width of the second button to be twice the width of the first and 2) use weightx values of .33 and .66.

Another option is to use the Relative Layout which was designed for this requirement.

Also, get rid of frame.setSize(...) and instead use frame.pack() before you make the frame visible to see the difference. Your solution only appears to work because you manually set the size. The relationship between the buttons will change as the user resizes the width of the frame.
